# How to create a comparable Image

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a `DataGridView` which has been bound to a generic `BindingList`. I want to be able to apply *sort* and *search* on columns of type `DataGridViewImageColumn`. *The basic idea is to store a name into the image `Tag` and use is for sorting and searching.* How can I do that?

It seems several ways to do it:

1. Creating a new class inheriting `System.Drawing.Image` and making it comparable.

   - `Image` is an abstract class and if I inherit from it (as well as `IComparable` interface), I'll encounter with this error message: The type 'System.Drawing.Image' has no constructors defined. ***What's the problem here? Image is an `abstract` not a `sealed` class, but it doesn't allow me to inherit it!***
2. Using protected override `ApplySortCore` method of inherited class from `BindingList<T>`.

   - This method is like so:

     ```
     class MyBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
     {
         ...
         protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop,
                                               ListSortDirection direction)
         {
             if (prop.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(Image)))
             {
                 /* I have no idea! */
             }
         }
     }
     ```
3. Creating a new `DataGridViewColumn` inheriting from `DataGridViewImageColumn`.

   - This doesn't seem to be easy and may be used if other ideas are unusable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way!

---

**MyBindingList**

```
class MyBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    ...
    protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop,
                                          ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(Image)))
        {
            _SortPropertyCore = prop;
            _SortDirectionCore = direction;

            var items = this.Items;
            Func<T, object> func =
                new Func<T, object>(t => (prop.GetValue(t) as Image).Tag);

            switch (direction)
            {
                case ListSortDirection.Ascending:
                    items = items.OrderBy(func).ToList();
                    break;

                case ListSortDirection.Descending:
                    items = items.OrderByDescending(func).ToList();
                    break;
            }

            ResetItems(items as List<T>);
            ResetBindings();
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    private void ResetItems(List<T> items)
    {
        base.ClearItems();

        for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < items.Count; itemIndex++)
        {
            base.InsertItem(itemIndex, items[itemIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**MyDataObject**

```
class MyDataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    public Image MyProp
    {
        get
        {
            return CreateComparableImage(myImage, "myImage");
        }
    }

    private Image CreateComparableImage(Image image, string alias)
    {
        Image taggedImage = new Bitmap(image);
        taggedImage.Tag = alias;

        return taggedImage;
    }
}
```

---

**Form**

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    ...

    void BindDGV()
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns["myColumnName"].DataPropertyName = "MyProp";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = MyBindingList<MyDataObject>(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class (X) that incapsulates System.Drawing. Image + ImageAlias string property.  Bind your image column to X.Image and search over X.ImageAlias.

Sorry but don't have a coding tool on my hands to provide an example, but this is a basic idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good idea! But I need implementation- Thanks

Comment: I created a class named `ComparableImage` inherited from `IComparable` and added two properties as you mentioned above.

Now, if I bind `DataGridViewImageColumn` to a property of type `ComparableImage`, it would be able to sort but can not display encapsulated image. (I tried to handle `DataError` event by passing the inner Image to the cell value but data-binding mechanism prevents from it. Because I've tried to set an image into a property of type `ComparableImage`.)

If I bind `ComparableImage.Image` to the DGV, it can not detect owner class and so cannot sort it. Indicate some code please.